# How to extract an embedded link from an as text saved html document OR how to use xidel to extract the correct link?

Tags: windows, batch-file, awk, sed, xidel

I am on Windows and I am using the "Git for windows" tools in batch files.
My etracted code from html site looks like this:

```
<a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="ZLl54 Dysyo" href="./g/git-for-windows/c/jgZ6P7bo7Fo"><div class="t17a0d"><span class="o1DPKc">[ANNOUNCE] Git for Windows 2.41.0</span></div><div class="WzoK">Dear Git users, I hereby announce that Git for Windows 2.41.0 is available from: https://</div></a>
```

and I want to extract **/g/git-for-windows/c/jgZ6P7bo7Fo** with sed or awk.
The first part is always the same /g/git-for-windows/c/ but the ending of the url part differs.

What I did:
`sed 's/^.*\("./g/".*"><div\").*$/\1/' text.txt | tee text2.txt` but it doesn't work.

What I want:
I want to extract the upper most (always latest) link to a new release of "Git for Windows" from website https://groups.google.com/g/git-for-windows. The decription shows Announce. Here are my steps:

```
xidel https://groups.google.com/g/git-for-windows --printed-node-format html -e "//'Links:',//a" | tee text.txt
```

to get the website as text.
Then I used `cat text.txt | grep -F "announce" | head -1 | tee text1.txt`.
The result is the exctracted code I posted above.

My questions:
How to use sed or awk correctly to extract the link **/g/git-for-windows/c/jgZ6P7bo7Fo** from the code?
Or how to use xidel in a better way to get better extractable results in text file.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding you, if you were trying to retrieve the download URL for Git-For-Windows, you could do that very simply in PowerShell. Example for 64-bit version:```Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -URI 'https://api.github.com/repos/git-for-windows/git/releases/latest' | ForEach-Object Assets | Where-Object Name -Like '*64-bit.exe' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Browser_Download_URL```. For the 32-bit version you'd just change the `-Like` string to `'*32-bit.exe'`. You could save that to a variable then download it using ```Invoke-WebRequest -URI …``` too.

Comment: Obviously, if you wanted to do this from a batch file, to stay on topic, then you'd save it to a variable like this: ```@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -URI 'https://api.github.com/repos/git-for-windows/git/releases/latest' | ForEach-Object Assets | Where-Object Name -Like '*64-bit.exe' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Browser_Download_URL" 2^>NUL') Do @Set "URL=%%G"```. Then use `%URL%` elsewhere in your code as required.

Comment: Good evening. Thank you for your answer. I don't want to download any asset from the Github repros, I just wanted to get a solution to get the link out of the code posted. For downloading latest or newest (pre-releases included) assets from Github, etc. I use the python script lastversion (https://github.com/dvershinin/lastversion). It also features a version comparing switch -gt. As I posted the question, my extracted html-code firstly got shown as html converted result. Magoo edited it so that the code is shown now ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following setting for the file is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q76495893.txt"

SET "extracted="
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 FOR %%o IN (%%e) DO (
  IF DEFINED extracted FOR /f "delims=<>" %%y IN ("%%o") DO SET "extracted=%%~y"&GOTO gotit
  IF "%%~o"=="href" SET "extracted=x"
 )
)
ECHO NOT found
GOTO :eof

:gotit
SET "extracted=%extracted:~1%"
ECHO extracted=%extracted%

GOTO :EOF
```

Since you tagged the post "batch"

Read the data from a file to `%%e`. Use standard list-processing of `%%e` to set `%%o` to each space-separated token in turn. When the `href` token is found, set `extracted` for use as a flag. When the next token arrives, use tokenising on the redirectors to grab the quoted string, and assign that, minus the quotes to `extracted` and done.

Well, almost. Need to remove the first character as you want the string minus the `.`

Comment: Great, your solution works like a charm and has the exact output. Thank you @Magoo for your fast answer. To be honest, firstly I needed some time to understand your formula ;-) But I learn by doing. PS: The system says I cannot upvote because of my low reputation, but feel it upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to call so many tools

Everything can be selected with XPath alone:

```
  xidel https://groups.google.com/g/git-for-windows -e "//a[contains(., 'ANNOUNCE')]/@href"
```

Comment: Your answer is really perfect, too. Just tried it out. Yesterday I did my first steps using xidel and I didn't find an exercise for that. Maybe you know a good online ressource for learning a more deeper usage? My task is to get html pasing done by xidel as first solution. Please feel your answer upvoted, thank you. As I wrote Magoo I cannot upvote, too less reputation as beginner here ;-)

Comment: For the most helpful answer I have chosen Magoo, because a batch solution at the point I stumbled was my first question and a xidel all-in-all solution the second. But both of you have somehow earned the "most helpful solution"- Thx a lot!

Comment: I think `-e "//a[contains(div/span,'ANNOUNCE')]/@href"` would be better, as it prevents duplicates.

Comment: @areich1976 I'd say, have a look at https://github.com/benibela/xidel/issues/67.

Comment: @Reino thanks for the really good link for xidel an your add-on for the use

Comment: @Reino But perhaps that is too much as an introduction

Comment: For all readers wanting to use the xidel full solution: `xidel https://groups.google.com/g/git-for-windows -e "//a[contains(div/span,'ANNOUNCE')]/@href" | head -1 - | cut -c2-` Put it into a `FOR /F` loop (escape the pipes) to set it as variable or `echo/tee` it into a text file. The `head` command chooses the newest result and the `cut -c2-` eliminates the leading point.

Comment: @areich1976 I just searched around, and found a basic XPath game: https://topswagcode.com/xpath/#

Comment: @BeniBela Just try it out. Thank you for the link ;-)

Comment: @areich1976 If you simply want the first result, then there's no need for other tools (kinda strange to see Bash tools in this Windows command-line btw). Xidel can of course do this too: `-e "(//a[contains(div/span,'ANNOUNCE')])[1]/substring(@href,2)"`.

Comment: @Reino Thank you. xidel is really a great tool.  I am only a hobby coder and learned on DOS in the late 80th, so I still use Windows cmd-programing. The Bash tools are shorter in pipes and really easy to use, they have a wide range of functions. Sometimes there are formatting issues. Regarding my simple needs they run perfect. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
curl https://...  | grep -E -o ">\[ANNOUNCE.{0,800}" | grep ">\[ANNOUNCE.*href" | sed 's/<\/span.*href="\.\([^"]*\).*/ \1/'
```

Comment: I get a "path is not valid" error. Can you please add some explanation to your solution? Thank you for your input and help.

Comment: Please try to replace `https://...` with valid url. I shortened command line to be more concise

Comment: Code works! Just had to escape the `^<` within the sed-command. On Windows use `curl https://groups.google.com/g/git-for-windows | grep -E -o ">\[ANNOUNCE.{0,800}" | grep ">\[ANNOUNCE.*href" | sed 's/^<\/span.*href="\.\([^"]*\).*/ \1/'` A bit late now but thank you @Renat for the grep-sed varant. I try to understand the  {0,800} in the grep part.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon you already having the shown string as the content of a file named `text1.txt`, then a batch file could retrieve the required substring like this:

```bash
@Set /P "URL=" 0<"text1.txt"
@For /F Tokens^=2^ Delims^=^" %%G In ("%URL:*href=%") Do @Set "URL=%%~G"
@Echo %URL:~1%
```

How it works:

1. Save the first line of `text1.txt` as the content of a variable named `URL`.
2. Expand that variable, replacing everything up to and including the first instance of the string `href` with nothing, (`="./g/git-for-windows/c/jgZ6P7bo7Fo"><div class="t17a0d"><span class="o1DPKc">[ANNOUNCE] Git for Windows 2.41.0</span></div><div class="WzoK">Dear Git users, I hereby announce that Git for Windows 2.41.0 is available from: https://</div></a>` ). Then delimit it by doublequotes, asking for the second token, (`=` being the first). This results in the full URL only, (`./g/git-for-windows/c/jgZ6P7bo7Fo`), overwriting the initial variable value.
3. Expand the resulting variable skipping the first character, `%URL:~1%`.

---

If you just wanted the ending part, then:

```bash
@Set /P "URL=" 0<"text1.txt"
@For /F Tokens^=2^ Delims^=^" %%G In ("%URL:*href=%") Do @Echo %%~nxG
```

Comment: Thankx @Compo, it also works perfect. :-) It was my fault, I did not pushd'd within cmd to the correct dir before testing. A beginner's failure from me.